# Connecting multiple computers and monitors to 1 mouse & keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, multiple-computers

What is the best way to connect multiple computers (say 4 or 5) to multiple monitors (same number) but only using 1 mouse and 1 keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

To do this you will use a **KVM Switch** like the [**IOGEAR 4-Port USB KVM Switch**](http://amzn.to/2kGKbxf) (this one will work for 4 computers.)

You plug in your keyboard and mouse to the switch, and the switch has cables going to the four PCs. You switch which PC to control with a button.

Another option is to use a **Software KVM Switch**. Which works by plugging in the keyboard and mouse in one computer and installing the software on all of them. You switch which system to control using a predefined hotkey.

One of the best software for this is **Synergy** (https://symless.com/synergy), but it will cost you a few dollars. Another popular one is **Input Director** (http://www.inputdirector.com/index.html), which is free.